# Why does my Windows 10 batch script not resume properly after shutting and opening the laptop lid?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, batch, putty

I have a batch script that runs on startup on my Windows 10 laptop.

The intention of the batch script is to keep an ssh tunnel open to another machine at all times when the laptop is on. The batch script does the following:

- sleep for 5 seconds
- run `plink` with a stored PuTTy configuration to open the required ssh tunnel
- inside the `plink` session, print the date / time and then run `cat` (so it's just sitting there eating any characters that anyone might type into the command prompt)
- when `plink` exits, print a "tunnel died" message and then loop back round to the start

The stored PuTTy configuration has TCP keepalives sent every 5 seconds.

If I shut the lid of the laptop and open it again, the command window is there with the last date / time message printed so it looks as though the tunnel is open. However, there is no plink.exe listed in the Task Manager, and from the other machine I can see the tunnel is in fact not open. When I hit a key in the command prompt, the script springs back to life and prints the "tunnel died" message then loops back around and opens the tunnel again.

If, instead of simply shutting the lid, I turn off WiFi on the laptop - everything behaves as expected (the script continues looping round with each call to `plink` failing and returning instantly).

I'm not sure if this is a `plink` issue or a Windows 10 / command prompt issue. Has anyone come across this and can advise? Desired behaviour would be that when the laptop lid is opened, the script realises that `plink` has failed / exited and prints the "tunnel died" message then loops round and starts the tunnel again.

Edited to add: The Windows settings for "When I shut the lid" is "Sleep" (for both battery and plugged in). The batch script in its entirety is as follows:

```
@echo off
:start
sleep 5s
plink -no-antispoof -R 5999:localhost:5999 garibaldi "date ; if sleep 15 | nc localhost 5999 |grep -q RFB 2>/dev/null ; then cat ; fi"
echo tunnel died %date% %time%
goto start
```

where `garibaldi` is the name of the saved PuTTy config and the part in double quotes is the script that runs on the remote host. (The purpose of the tunnel is to allow me to use VNC to connect back in to the laptop over the tunnel via remote port forwarding on port 5999; "RFB" is part of the string that RealVNC server issues when you connect to that port. The remote port forwarding arrangement / VNC works perfectly fine when the tunnel is up.)

Comment: You need to add the recovery of the connection into the script itself.  How you accomplish that is more of a Stack Overflow question though.

Comment: Shutting and opening back the lid of your Personal Computer are usually by default used as triggers for sleep or hibernation Power Settings. As far as we can understand, you have not manually handled these events in your Batch Script. Can we see it? Can you insert it in the body of your question? What are your current settings related to the Power Settings upon the shutting and opening back of the lid?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai I have edited with more details.

Comment: Can you please change your Power Options so that your "_When I shut the lid_" Option gets to "_Do nothing_" and then try again?